# DELPHI Google GEOCODE Json parser

Tags: json, delphi, google-geocoder

Using google geocode API, when i using PHP i can do with this:

```
$request = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-6.408107,107.468262&key=AIzaSyCUzlhl-ibUJsKCwWDwsZqjiW7EP_On30g&sensor=false");
$json = json_decode($request, true);
echo $json['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'];
echo $json['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'];
```

now, how do it on DELPHI? i try this but got EXCEPTION

```
  myjson:=RESTResponse1.Content;
  JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(myjson) as TJSONObject;
  JSONObject2 := JSONObject.GetValue('results') as TJSONObject;
  arrayjson := JSONObject2.GetValue('address_components') as TJSONArray;
  currcond := arrayjson.Items[0] as TJSONObject;
  showmessage(currcond.GetValue('long_name').Value);
```

Comment: What exception did you get? Where's the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: i got `access violation address`, the REST result is 
[link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-6.408107,107.468262&key=AIzaSyCUzlhl-ibUJsKCwWDwsZqjiW7EP_On30g&sensor=false)
i use `TrestClient` and `Restresponse`

Comment: Access Violation at what address etc? Those numbers do mean something. Have you stepped into debugging to see if one of those assignments returns `nil`? That would cause such an exception. Which line do you get the exception on?

Comment: at address `0x009ebf24` and stop at this unit `system.json`
`function TJSONObject.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FMembers.Count;
end;`

Comment: Have you tried searching for existing implementations? A simple search turned up this useful result: http://gloegg.blogspot.com/2011/06/delphi-and-geocoding.html

Comment: Classic case of slightly muddled thinking. Nothing to do with geocode. Don't let that get in the way. Concentrate on the json.  This is just a single? Please json parsing exercise. Spend some time learning how to parse json. Read example code. There is a lot around. Read the json spec so you understand the concepts. Know the difference between object, array and value. Etc. Make it your goal to learn and understand. Then you can write the code yourself. Far better than hoping we will do it leaving you knowing no more than you do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON `results` element you access in your PHP code is an array type. Yet, in your Delphi code, you're trying to access it as an object. This causes `arrayjson` to return `nil`, and when you try to access `arrayjson`, since it doesn't exist, you get an `Access Violation` exception.

Instead, you should read the first `results` element as an array. Then, either read the first (`0`) element in that array, or iterate through all of them - depending on the need.

Answer (score -1):

See code examples at https://github.com/hgourvest/superobject

This library is easier to use (compare your source code and mine) and is in general more tested and more reliable (just search SO about problems with Delphi bundled DBX JSON), which is sadly usual with recent Delphi "out of the box" libraries.

[image]

Simplistic (but not very optimal if you need several data items, rather than a single one !!! ) approach would be like

```
var json: iSuperObject;

json := TSuperObject.ParseStirng( RESTResponse1.Content );

ShowMessage( json[ 'results[0].address_components[0].long_name' ].AsString );

json := nil;  // clean-up after you no more need it
```

Better would be something like that (did not checked, just a quick draft):

```
var json1, json2: iSuperObject;
    arr1, arr2: TSuperArray;
    i1, i2: integer;

json1 := TSuperObject.ParseStirng( RESTResponse1.Content );
arr1 := json1.AsArray;
for i1 := 0 to arr1.Length-1 do begin
  json2 := arr1.O[i1].O['address_components'];
  arr2  := json2.AsArray;
  for i2 := 0 to arr2.Length-1 do begin 
    ShowMessage( arr2.O[i2].S['long_name'] );
  end;
end;

json2 := nil; json1 := nil;
```

Comment: Here you propose that the asker introduces a third party dependency on a different JSON parser. Are you implying that the JSON parser that the asker is using cannot parse this JSON? Please make this clear. If you are going to suggest that the asker takes a new library, you should provide motivation for that.

Comment: Topic starter did not limit his question to using the specific library, more so his inexperience suggests he did not created to much code bound to DBX JSON, so any library suits.

Comment: Prospects of novice user being able to successfully install some third party library? This is poor advice indeed,

Comment: Now you imply the topicstarter is not capable of downloading and copying files. If that assumption of yours is correct then he would be not suited to be a programmer and his problems can not be fixed with any library. You also imply while topicstarter is not capable of copying files he somehow is capable of tracking and working around or fixing all the bugs DBX JSON has in different Delphi versions. O'RLY ?

Comment: The built in parser is perfectly capably of parsing this JSON, and it is disingenuous to imply otherwise. If you want to add that to the answer though, as justification, go ahead.

Comment: I already added it. Also provoking a newby into investing is time into learning and writing code with an inferior library just gambling upon topicstarter would never have jobs with any real, non-trivial data or when he will - would have free labour offer to rewrite all the already written code is hardly a responsible suggestion.

Comment: it seems to be good....
but is this library suppport for andoroid & iOS?

Comment: There are versions with that support. Why don't you use the built in library? It's documented, there are many examples. Works on all platforms. No requirement to include third party software. Without a good reason to change you are making life hard for yourself. Do you know JSON well? Do you know what the terms object, array and value mean in the context of JSON? If you don't then you are wasting everybody's time, especially your own.

Answer (score -1):

Using ALJsonDoc that you can download here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/alcinoe/

or using the svn is much more better :
(svn) https://svn.code.sf.net/p/alcinoe/code/

You can do it very easily like this :

```
function _FindLatLongU(const aQuery: String;
                                     var aID_Gmap: String;
                                     var aLatitude,
                                         aLongitude: Double;
                                     const aHighAccuracy: boolean = True): boolean;

var aHttp: Twin_HttpTaskU;
    aHTTPResponse: IHTTPResponse;
    aBytes: Tbytes;
    AResponseContentStream: TMemoryStream;
    ADecodedResponseContentStream: TStream;
    aFreeDecodedResponseContentStream: boolean;
    aJsonDoc: TalJsonDocumentU;
    S1: String;

begin

  try

    //init var
    Result := False;
    aID_Gmap := '';
    aLatitude := 999;
    aLongitude := 999;

    //create local object
    aHttp := Twin_HttpTaskU.Create;
    AResponseContentStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    ADecodedResponseContentStream := nil;
    aFreeDecodedResponseContentStream := False;
    aJsonDoc := TalJsonDocumentU.Create(true);
    try

      //init aJsonDoc
      aJsonDoc.Options := [doNodeAutoCreate];

      //do the http request
      aHTTPResponse := aHttp.HttpClient.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'+   // json indicates output as JSON
                                             'address=' + TnetEncoding.URL.Encode(aQuery) + '&'+              // The address that you want to geocode.
                                             'sensor=false&'+                                      // Indicates whether or not the geocoding request comes from a device with a location sensor. This value must be either true or false.
                                             'language=en',
                                            AResponseContentStream); // AResponseContent

      //normally this never happen because it's raise an exception in previous step
      if aHTTPResponse.StatusCode <> 200 then exit(False);

      //decode the result if necessary
      {$if defined(_USE_ZLIB)}
      if ALSameTextU(aHTTPResponse.ContentEncoding, 'gzip') then begin
        ADecodedResponseContentStream := TDecompressionStream.Create(AResponseContentStream, 15 + 16); // 15 is the default mode.
        aFreeDecodedResponseContentStream := True;                                                     // 16 is to enable gzip mode.  http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced
      end
      else ADecodedResponseContentStream := AResponseContentStream;
      {$ELSE}
      ADecodedResponseContentStream := AResponseContentStream;
      {$ENDIF}

      //put the response in aJsonDoc
      ADecodedResponseContentStream.Position := 0;
      setlength(aBytes, ADecodedResponseContentStream.Size);
      ADecodedResponseContentStream.ReadBuffer(pointer(aBytes)^, ADecodedResponseContentStream.Size);
      S1 := Tencoding.UTF8.GetString(aBytes);  //{
                                               //   "results" : [
                                               //      {
                                               //         "address_components" : [
                                               //            {
                                               //               "long_name" : "Toledo",
                                               //               "short_name" : "Toledo",
                                               //               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                                               //            },
                                               //            {
                                               //               "long_name" : "Toledo",
                                               //               "short_name" : "Toledo",
                                               //               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_4", "political" ]
                                               //            },
                                               //            {
                                               //               "long_name" : "Vega de Toledo",
                                               //               "short_name" : "Vega de Toledo",
                                               //               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
                                               //            },
                                               //            {
                                               //               "long_name" : "Toledo",
                                               //               "short_name" : "TO",
                                               //               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
                                               //            },
                                               //            {
                                               //               "long_name" : "Castile-La Mancha",
                                               //               "short_name" : "CM",
                                               //               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
                                               //            },
                                               //            {
                                               //               "long_name" : "Spain",
                                               //               "short_name" : "ES",
                                               //               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
                                               //            }
                                               //         ],
                                               //         "formatted_address" : "Toledo, Toledo, Spain",
                                               //         "geometry" : {
                                               //            "bounds" : {
                                               //               "northeast" : {
                                               //                  "lat" : 39.88605099999999,
                                               //                  "lng" : -3.9192423
                                               //               },
                                               //               "southwest" : {
                                               //                  "lat" : 39.8383676,
                                               //                  "lng" : -4.0629256
                                               //               }
                                               //            },
                                               //            "location" : {
                                               //               "lat" : 39.8628316,
                                               //               "lng" : -4.027323099999999
                                               //            },
                                               //            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
                                               //            "viewport" : {
                                               //               "northeast" : {
                                               //                  "lat" : 39.88605099999999,
                                               //                  "lng" : -3.9192423
                                               //               },
                                               //               "southwest" : {
                                               //                  "lat" : 39.8383676,
                                               //                  "lng" : -4.0629256
                                               //               }
                                               //            }
                                               //         },
                                               //         "place_id" : "ChIJ8f21C60Lag0R_q11auhbf8Y",
                                               //         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
                                               //      }
                                               //   ],
                                               //   "status" : "OK"
                                               //}
      aJsonDoc.LoadFromJSONString(S1);

      // "OK" indicates that no errors occurred; the address was successfully parsed and at least one geocode was returned.
      if ALSametextU(aJsonDoc.ChildNodes['status'].Text, 'OK') then begin

        // get only the first result (it's the most accurate)
        if ((aHighAccuracy) and (aJsonDoc.ChildNodes['results'].ChildNodes.Count = 1)) or
           ((not aHighAccuracy) and (aJsonDoc.ChildNodes['results'].ChildNodes.Count > 0)) then begin

          // extract ID of Google Maps, it looks like hash and must be saved as text.
          // An example: EisxMjAwMyBNYWluIFN0cmVldCwgQnJpYXJ3b29kLCBOWSAxMTQzNSwgVVNB
          aID_Gmap := aJSONDoc.ChildNodes['results'].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes['place_id'].Text;

          //"geometry" : {
          //   "location" : {
          //      "lat" : 37.4224553,
          //      "lng" : -122.0843062
          //   },
          //   "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
          //   "viewport" : {
          //      "northeast" : {
          //         "lat" : 37.42380428029149,
          //         "lng" : -122.0829572197085
          //      },
          //      "southwest" : {
          //         "lat" : 37.42110631970849,
          //        "lng" : -122.0856551802915
          //      }
          //   }
          //}
          with aJSONDoc.ChildNodes['results'].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes['geometry'] do begin
            aLongitude := ALStrToFloatU(ChildNodes['location'].ChildNodes['lng'].Text, ALDefaultFormatSettingsU);
            aLatitude  := ALStrToFloatU(ChildNodes['location'].ChildNodes['lat'].Text, ALDefaultFormatSettingsU);
          end;

          //set result to true
          result := true;

        end;

      end;

    finally
      AResponseContentStream.Free;
      if aFreeDecodedResponseContentStream then aDecodedResponseContentStream.Free;
      aJsonDoc.Free;
      aHttp.Free;
    end;

  except
    result := False;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: And again, unnecessarily offering OP to use another third-party JSON library. The other answer here offering to use `SuperObject` was actually downvoted twice because of this. Also, "Very easily" with much more code...?

Comment: Jerry, maybe you must first read the question, it's ask nowhere how to use DBXJson, But ask how to parse a json content!! and it's stupid to explain how to use DBXJson when DBXjson is simply the most badly designed json parser and the most slowest i never saw (around 100x  more slowest than alcinoe or superobject or anything else for exemple and without exageration). Also Where you see very much code?? Alongitude = aJSONDoc.ChildNodes['results'].ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes['geometry'].ChildNodes['location'].ChildNodes['lng'].float is much more code for you ?? please gave equivalent with dbxjson!

Comment: OP posted 6 lines of code with just one tiny error which needs to be corrected. You have 184 lines of code. If I brought my old car to you and said it has a flat tire, would you offer me to buy a completely different car instead of repairing the flat tire? It's a good idea of course, but that's not what was asked.

Comment: The more you write the code for people, the more they will come back to ask us to do it again :-)

Comment: @jerry: oooh i didn't know that we must gave low quality response corresponding to the number of line of quote requester write :) so if i understand you good i must write thousands of lines of code in my question to have a high quality answer right ?? their is nothing wrong in my answer i simply share my own experience with google gmap and json, and i will not reduce the number of line of code to be more adequate with the number of line of code the requester wrote !

Comment: This is precisely the reason why closing questions no longer allows anyone to post answers. This question should have been closed a long time ago. For the record, I am not the one who downvoted.

Comment: @jerry i would like that someone post a very long answer like i do to your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557342/how-to-conditionally-make-a-property-save-to-the-dfm-or-not ... Because right now (just now) i need also to know a way to do this but without stored keyword that not work for child component :(